# Нажать на ссылку с определенным атрибутом href

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

На странице есть ссылка вида:

```
<a href="https://test.ru/reg.php?x=xxxxxx&b=qqqqq..........">LINK</a>
```

Как заставить сделать клик по ссылке атрибут href которой содержит часть текста `https://test.ru/reg.php`

Буду благодарен за информацию!

Answer (score -1):

На чистом JS можно использовать `querySelector`:

```js
const a = document.querySelector('a[href*="https://test.ru/reg.php"]'); // получить ссылку, в адресе которой есть нужный текст

a.addEventListener('click', function(e) { // замена перехода по ссылке записью в консоль, для демонстрации
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("clicked");
});

a.click(); // клик по ссылке
```

```html
<a href="https://test.ru/reg.php?x=xxxxxx&b=qqqqq..........">LINK</a>
```